# Nohup is not working as expected

Tags: shell, ssh, nohup

On a fresh install of OpenMediaVault (debian based), I try to start and keep `rsync` in background when leaving my ssh session.

I've always do that with success in previous versions..
But now with this new version, my command is killed when my session is terminated.

I'm not understanding why !

command :

`nohup rsync -ah /src /dst &`

Comment: Are you using a bash different from the standard? I mean `fish` or `ksh`. Try to disown manually the `pid` with `disown`

Comment: nope i'm using bash as is. i'm using disown instead..